# Prove that a number $n$ can be represented in $2^{n-1}$ ways of summation...

Tags: number-theory, summation

The question as just as the title reads-

> Prove that a number $n$ can be represented in $2^{n-1}$ ways of summation

We know that-

> $1=1+0$ So,it can be represented in $1$ way of sum as indicated by the form $2^{n-1}=2^0=1$
>
> Similarly,$3$ can be represented in $1+1+1$ or $2+1$ or $1+2$ or $3+0$ .So,total $4$ ways as indicated by the formula $2^{3-1}=2^2=4.$

So,I need to prove that any number $n$ can be expressed in $2^{n-1}$ ways for summation.

I need some help to start on the problem.

Thanks for any response!!

Comment: Try coming up with a recurrence relation.

Comment: @Crostul I tried but it seems that induction will be a long and tiring way for this....For every increase of $+1$ in the number the number of ways of summation increases by $2^{n-1}$...so its going to be tiring....

Comment: With $0$ being allowed, a number $n$ can be represented in $\infty$ ways of summation.

Comment: @barakmanos I am talking about integers only...

Comment: @tatan: $0$ is integer.

Comment: @barakmanos How can $3$ be expressed in an infinite ways of sum?

Comment: @tatan: $3+0,3+0+0,3+0+0+0,3+0+0+0+0,\dots$

Comment: @barakmanos $0+0+0...\infty$=0 so,its useless to write $0$ hundreds of times...isn't it?

Comment: @tatan: They are nevertheless different ways of representing $3$ as a sum of integers. So unless you **EXCLUDE** $0$, there are infinitely many ways to represent every integer as a sum.

Comment: @tatan: BTW, all I'm saying is that you don't need to represent $3$ as $3+0$, but simply as $3$. It is a sum of a single element.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following string
$$(1 \ 1 \ \cdots \ 1)$$
made of $n$ ciphers $1$. Between any two consecutive ciphers, you can choose to put the symbol "$+$" or the symbol "$)+($". Since you have to make $n-1$ choices between two symbols, you have a total of $2^{n-1}$ possibilities.

As an example:
$$5=3+2$$
corresponds to
$$5=(1 \ + \ 1 \ + \ 1 \ )+( \ 1 \ + \ 1)$$
and in this case we have chosen the sequence of symbols $+,+, )+( , +$

Comment: Great solution! But I would suggest "numeral" or "symbol" in place of the word "cipher."

Answer (score 1):

Given any general $n$, look at the number of ways to represent $n$ as the sum of $1$ positive integer, sum of $2$ positive integers, $\dots$, sum of $n$ positive integers.

Now, we know that the number of positive integer solutions to
$$x_1+x_2+\dots x_r=n$$
is given by
$$X_r=\binom{n-1}{r-1}$$

So, to find the number of ways of expressing $n$ as a sum, you only need to find
$$\sum_{r=1}^n X_r = \sum_{r=1}^n \binom{n-1}{r-1} = 2^{n-1}$$

There are two ways to prove the final statement

1. [Proof by WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%5Cbinom%7Bn-1%7D%7Br-1%7D%20from%20r%3D1%20to%20n)
2. Proof by strong induction where in the induction step you simply need to repeatedly use the formula $\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n}{r-1}=\binom{n+1}{r}$.

I'll leave it to you to decide upon which method to use for the proof :)